# SQL - Multiple fields are updated instead of one

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb

I have four columns: ID, STARTTIME, ENDINGTIME and DURATION.

The table is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    STARTTIME TIMESTAMP,
    ENDINGTIME TIMESTAMP,
    DURATION TIME);
```

The ID is an auto_increment column. Then I've the code for inserting a new STARTTIME:

```
INSERT INTO tableName(STARTTIME) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Secondly I've the code for updating the row with the biggest ID to set the ENDINGTIME:

```
SET @latestInsertID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tableName);
UPDATE tableName SET ENDINGTIME=(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) WHERE ID=@latestInsertID;
```

Now I can execute both (all three) queries without getting an exception and the first query works totally fine (as I expected). But the last query updates (from the row I wanted to update) the ENDINGTIME as well as the STARTTIME.  Why doesn't it just update the ENDINGTIME?

Thank you for every solution!

Comment: For definitive answer add your `CREATE` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATETIME` instead of `TIMESTAMP` ([MWE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d3547bab7f784cf4bc371a60bd99f058))

[Here's](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestamp/) why:

> The timestamp field is generally used to define at which moment in time a row was added or updated and by default will automatically be assigned the current datetime when a record is inserted or updated. The automatic properties only apply to the first TIMESTAMP in the record; subsequent TIMESTAMP columns will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Educated guess. Column is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(
    -- ...
    STARTTIME TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Or there is underlying trigger that perfroms same logic.

Comment: Thanke you for your answer! I don't have any trigger and I've inserted the CREATE-query above.